# How to convert Spark RDD to JSON object java

Tags: java, json, cassandra, apache-spark, rdd

When using Cassandra with Spark, my RDD that i recover looks like this:

```
MAPPED RDD: [Person{id='8', name='Hans', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='7', name='Loren', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='1', name='John', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='5', name='Adam', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='6', name='Kit', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='10', name='Lacey', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='9', name='Phil', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='2', name='Anna', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='4', name='Angel', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}, Person{id='3', name='Andrew', birthDate='Fri Oct 03 15:07:38 EDT 2014'}]
```

How can I make it look like a JSON object? Right now i'm doing it by manually replacing portions of the Mapped RDD to make it look like a JSON, but I want a function, or quick way to map a Spark RDD to a JSON, so it can handle different data RDDs.

Comment: Please, explain, how did you get this RDD? Using spark-cassandra-connector? What is the query? Or sc.cassandraTable[(Int, Long)](keyspace, columnFamily).select("a", "b")?

Comment: @PavelAjtkulov I use spark-cassandra-connector. Here is my code to get the RDD: `JavaRDD<String> mappedRddOnCassandra = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "people", Person.class)
                .map(new Function<Person, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(Person person) throws Exception {
                     return person.toString();
                    }
                });`

Comment: Were you able to do this?